# Ruby on Rails: Show results between 2 dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord, between

I am using jquery date picker to pick two dates when searching my database. At the moment the search will only search on an exact start date and exact end date, but I want the user to be able to pick two dates, where they can search between the dates.

Here is my model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :edited_date, :end_date, :entry_date, :exception_pm, :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech

validates_presence_of :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :end_date, :exception_pm, :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech





def self.search(search_client, search_industry, search_role, search_tech, search_business_div, search_project_owner, search_exception_pm, search_status, search_start_date, search_end_date, search_keywords) 
  return scoped unless search_client.present? || search_industry.present? || search_role.present? || search_tech.present? || search_business_div.present? || search_project_owner.present? || search_exception_pm.present? || search_status.present? || search_start_date.present? || search_end_date.present? || search_keywords.present?

if search_start_date != ""
search_start_date = Date.parse(search_start_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end
if search_end_date != ""
search_end_date = Date.parse(search_end_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end



  where(['client LIKE ? AND industry LIKE ? AND role LIKE ? AND tech LIKE ? AND business_div LIKE ? AND project_owner LIKE ? AND exception_pm LIKE ? AND status LIKE ? AND start_date LIKE ? AND end_date LIKE ? AND keywords LIKE ?', "%#{search_client}%", "%#{search_industry}%" , "%#{search_role}%" , "%#{search_tech}%" , "%#{search_business_div}%" , "%#{search_project_owner}%" , "%#{search_exception_pm}%" , "%#{search_status}%", "%#{search_start_date}%", "%#{search_end_date}%","%#{search_keywords}%"])



end


def self.paginated_for_index(projects_per_page, current_page)
    paginate(:per_page => projects_per_page, :page => current_page)
  end

end
```

Here is my search view:

```
<h1>Search</h1>

<% if @project_search.total_entries > 0 %>
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>

Client :
<%= select(@projects, :client, Project.all.map {|p| [p.client]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:client]) %></br>

Industry :
<%= select(@projects, :industry, Project.all.map {|p| [p.industry]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:industry]) %></br>

Role :
<%= select(@projects, :role, Project.all.map {|p| [p.role]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:role]) %></br>

Technologies :
<%= select(@projects, :tech, Project.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:tech]) %></br>

Business Division :

<%= select(@projects, :business_div, Project.all.map {|p| [p.business_div]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:business_div]) %></br>

Project Owner :
<%= select(@projects, :project_owner, Project.all.map {|p| [p.project_owner]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:project_owner]) %></br>

Exception PM
<%= select(@projects, :exception_pm, Project.all.map {|p| [p.exception_pm]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:exception_pm]) %></br>


Start Date :

<%=  text_field_tag("start_date") %></br>


End Date :

<%= text_field_tag("end_date") %></br>


Status :

<%= select(@projects, :status, Project.all.map {|p| [p.status]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:status]) %></br>

Keywords :

<%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords] %></br>

<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>

<% end %>


<% if @search_performed %>
<h3><%=@project_search.total_entries%> results</h3>



<table class = "pretty">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable "project_name", "Project name" %> </th>
    <th><%= sortable "client", "Client" %></th>
<% if false %>
    <th>Exception pm</th>
    <th>Project owner</th>
<% end %>
    <th><%= sortable "tech", "Technologies" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "role", "Role" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "industry", "Industry" %></th>
<% if false %>
    <th>Financials</th>
    <th>Business div</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>End date</th>
    <th>Entry date</th>
    <th>Edited date</th>
    <th>Summary</th>
    <th>Lessons learned</tStackh>
    <th>Customer benifits</th>
    <th>Keywords</th>
    <!th></th>
    <!th></th>
    <!th></th>
<% end %>
  </tr>



<% @project_search.each do |t| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= t.project_name %></td>
    <td><%= t.client %></td>
<% if false %>
    <td><%= t.exception_pm %></td>
    <td><%= t.project_owner %></td>
<% end %>
    <td><%= t.tech %></td>
    <td><%= t.role %></td>
    <td><%= t.industry %></td>
<% if false %>
    <td><%= t.financials %></td>
    <td><%= t.business_div %></td>
    <td><%= t.status %></td>
    <td><%= l(t.start_date) if t.start_date? %></td>
    <td><%= l(t.end_date) if t.end_date? %></td>
    <td><%= t.entry_date %></td>
    <td><%= t.edited_date %></td>
    <td><%= t.summary %></td>
    <td><%= t.lessons_learned %></td>
    <td><%= t.customer_benifits %></td>
    <td><%= t.keywords %></td>
<% end %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', t %></td>
    <!td><%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
    <!td><%#= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<%end %>

<% if @search_performed %>
Results per page: <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,20,50], params[:per_page].to_i), :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location='?per_page='+this.value;}" %>

<% end %>

<% else %>
<h2> Sorry, there are no results matching your search. Please try again. </h2> 
<% end %>
<br />
<%# end %>

<% if @search_performed %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :per_page, params[:per_page] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :page, params[:page] %>

<%= will_paginate (@project_search) %>


<%= button_to "Search Again?", search_path, :method => "get" %>

<% end %>
<%= button_to "Home", projects_path, :method => "get" %>
```

and here is part of my controller:

```
def search

@search = params[:client], params[:industry], params[:role], params[:tech], params[:business_div], params[:project_owner], params[:exception_pm], params[:status], params[:start_date], params[:end_date], params[:keywords]

@project_search = Project.search(*@search).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginated_for_index(per_page, page)

@search_performed = !@search.reject! { |c| c.blank? }.empty? 

   @project = Project.new(params[:project])

respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end

end
```

Hopefully someone can help me. I'm new to rails so go easy :). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*: this is what your query should look like:

```
where(['client LIKE ? AND industry LIKE ? AND role LIKE ? AND tech LIKE ? AND business_div LIKE ? AND project_owner LIKE ? AND exception_pm LIKE ? AND status LIKE ? AND DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? AND DATE(end_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? AND keywords LIKE ?', 
      "%#{search_client}%", "%#{search_industry}%" , "%#{search_role}%" , "%#{search_tech}%" , "%#{search_business_div}%" , 
      "%#{search_project_owner}%" , "%#{search_exception_pm}%" , "%#{search_status}%", 
      search_start_date, search_end_date, search_start_date, search_end_date,"%#{search_keywords}%"
    ])
```

What we are doing is telling MySQL to take the date bit of the start and end dates, and make sure it is between the values we are providing it with.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have copied everything you did over to my code. I don't understand 2 new fields I have to pass over to my @search variable. Also, I'm not trying to get find a start date start point and end point, and an end date start point and end point. I'm just wanting to let the user give 2 dates, for example. start_date = 15/05/1991, and end_date = 28/06/2012, to show the projects during this period. Thanks again

Comment: Oh right. In that case, I'd say Benedikt's answer is the right one. You simply amend your query to use the `BETWEEN` statement like he suggests

Comment: Would you be able to explain where I would put @benedikt-koppel suggestion using my code? Don't really understand if I have to change my controller, or what parts of my model I need to change. Cheers

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment. All you'd need to do is change your query to the one I m proposing.

Comment: I have found a problem where, using your suggestion, the other fields of the search now don't work. I can search on the dates fine, but if I leave them blank, or search with the dates and another field. No results are returned.

Comment: I see. Ideally, you should create a scope that you can chain if the fields exist. Something like `scope :for_date_span, lambda {|from,to|  where(['DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? AND DATE(end_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?',from,to,from,to])}`. Then you can add this scope if the fields exist. Read more on scopes here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to show all projects that were live between `search_start_date` and `search_end_date`. So that would translate to the following logic:

- project started in the timeframe:

  `project.start_date BETWEEN search_start_date AND search_end_date`
- project ended in the timeframe:

  `project.end_date BETWEEN search_start_date AND search_end_date`
- project started before and ended after the timeframe:

  `project.start_date <= search_start_date AND project.end_date => search_end_date`

You can directly translate this to SQL and put it into your where command.

As a suggestion: I would change the question marks in your where command to named placeholders, as it makes your query much more readable. The ActiveRecord Querying guide has the details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions (section 2.2.1 Placeholder Conditions)

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) on Range conditions:

```
Client.where(created_at: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight)
```

That will produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.created_at BETWEEN '2008-12-21 00:00:00' AND '2008-12-22 00:00:00')
```

So you can search for fields between two dates using a range.